# How to round corners of a table without CSS?

Tags: html

I have the following 2x1 cell where I have an image in cell 1 and text in cell 2. I want rounded corners such as the examples found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp). I used `border-radius` but I still have hard corners. I cannot use CSS as this is for a newsletter that will be emailed out. I appreciate any insight.

```
<table border="3" width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse border-radius:15px 50px">
    <td style="border:none">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                    <img alt="" width="275" height="150" style="border-width: 0px" src="http://www.path.com/to/image.png"></img>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="border:none">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <span style="font-family: trebuchet ms,verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
                    <p>test text</p>
                    </span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Post up your CSS also.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with `border-collapse: collapse;` you need to use the `border-collapse: separate;`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      td > span {
        font-family: trebuchet ms,verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      td > img {
        /*   border-width: 0px; */
        border-radius: 15px 0 0 50px;  
      }

      body > table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-radius: 15px 50px;
        border: 3px solid #000;

      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
      <tr>
        <td>
            <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                          <img alt="" width="275" height="150"src="http://via.placeholder.com/275x150"></img>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <span>
                        <p>test text</p>
                        </span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Results in: 
[image]

You can see documentation about the different styles of border on tables at https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders and https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#collapsing-borders. The snippet above should work in an email or as a stand alone page but would recommend separating the CSS for a standalone page.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table tag from

```
<table border="3" width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse border-radius:15px 50px">
```

to

```
<table border="3" width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
```

And use this CSS

```
table {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

If you only want this rounded corner on the outer table, then give it an ID or a class and reference the new ID or class in the CSS instead of referencing all table elements.

Comment: I should clarify that I cannot use CSS as this is for a newsletter that will be blasted out. I hope this is helpful to someone else though.

Comment: Then use inline CSS

Comment: I have in the table tag (style) you referenced and it doesn't work.

Comment: <table border="3" width="723" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 2px solid; border-radius: 25px;"> Note that if your email vendor strips CSS, or if the receiver's vendor removes CSS then this won't work. It will be impossible to get the rounded borders, unless you use an image.